# Random JQuery .keypress() Question

Tags: jquery

Can a bot trigger the .keypress() event on an input field?

Comment: It _completely_ depends on the bot.

Comment: ahh, was hoping to secure a form by using an external input field that updated a hidden input field in the form on .keypress.

Comment: always be very wary of client-side 'security'. It's usually not secure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. Bot can be configured to do anything

Comment: "Bot can be configured to do anything" is a false statement.

Comment: it is true (either now or in the future). But it successes may vary.